# Creating unique dynamic URLs for my Firebase website?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, dynamic, server

This is a very newbie question, but I'm creating a website using Google Firebase & vanilla JS. I want to create a website where users can create their own collections of movies (which they search up from a movies API), and make their own lists, but also be able to search up their friends and see their collections.

So far, I have some individual user functionalities completed. They can make & customize their profile. The next step is to make functionalities so every user can make their movies collections and whatnot, which I can do.

What I'm wondering is how will I eventually hook it up so it creates a unique URL for each person and their movies collections? For example, a user is able to directly go to `https://www.example.com/userProfile?uid=314159`, etc. What tools or concepts do I need to learn to go ahead with making a website like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several components:

- Database (or broadly, storage). You'll need a place for users to store their collections etc. Since you're already allowing users to customize their profile, this probably isn't too big of a deal.
- ID generation: You can find several techniques for this. You could simply have a sequential ID (e.g. most DBs have an incremental integer as primary key), but you could also use [UUIDs/GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), recreate YouTube's random video IDs, ...
- The backend that hosts your frontend and communicates with your database. I assume Firebase takes care of most of that for you.
- The frontend that's actually displayed to your user. There are several techniques/frameworks for this, e.g. Single Page Application, serverside rendering, ... all things where there is a lot of documentation/tutorials for.

After generating an ID, you can store it in the table as part of the collection. Whenever the user visits the collection URL, you'll extract the id from the URL (e.g. using [path parameters in ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)), query the database for the right collection and all movies in it, then do whatever you want, i.e. display it to the user.

If you can do this for collections/movies, extending it to e.g. friend lists is quite trivial.

Your question is otherwise quite broad. Most parts (i.e. frameworks/tools) you can simply Google or look around for. You can choose to use frontend frameworks (React, AngularJS, ...) and others, which is all partially preference/experience and partially what fits your needs best (which is a whole discussion that isn't really suited for SO). Besides all that, you just have regular programming concepts. Some depending on the language, others just in general, i.e. OOP patterns such as the factory pattern. Giving you a good overview of all that is basically what getting a degree in Computer Science does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was wondering more about how to actually create the system where URLs will be created automatically for each user and their collections of movies, like dynamically creating URLs for pages, and those pages being filled with correlating information from the Firebase DB. I'm interested to know what technologies (Node? Express?) are used for these tasks, so I can start learning about them.

Comment: I'd say stick with what you're using. When the user creates a collection (and you're about to write it into your database), generate an ID and add that to the collection. After that, you can use e.g. Express to host your server-side API (and the frontend files) which would use e.g; path `/collections/:id` which allows using `req.params.id` to query the database for the collection. If you're already using something else that's similar to Express, you could add that logic there.